# Dual booting Windows8 and Ubuntu on 2 separate drives: the allocation slider: What is left what is right

Tags: dual-boot, 13.04, system-installation, hard-drive, windows-8

So I just added an old 120GB HDD that I scavenged from my dead xbox360 to my computer, and it works perfectly, I have used it already on windows simply to store files.

Now I want to use it to dual boot my existing Windows8 and Ubuntu. When in the installation menu, when it shows me the slider to allocate space, it automatically choses the second HDD(sdb).

As far as I know, the slider is used to choose how many space Windows(left) and Ubuntu(right) has allocated.

But since the second HDD is empty and Windows 8 is on the main HDD, why does it ask me how much to allocate? What is left and what is right?